# Excel min formula in offset formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to get left cell value of min value cell

i tryed this formula. but its not working

=OFFSET(min(AB2,AD2,AF2,AH2,AJ2),0,-1)

asking for correction in this formula

OR is there any neat and clean way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

With Office 365:

```
=FILTER(HSTACK(AA2,AC2,AE2,AG2,AI2),HSTACK(AB2,AD2,AF2,AH2,AJ2)=MIN(AB2,AD2,AF2,AH2,AJ2))
```

With let to minimize the number of references:

```
=LET(
    rng,AA2:AJ2,
    ot,FILTER(rng,ISODD(COLUMN(rng))),
    in,FILTER(rng,ISEVEN(COLUMN(rng))),
    FILTER(ot,in=MIN(in)))
```

---

With older versions:

```
=IF(AB2=MIN(AB2,AD2,AF2,AH2,AJ2),AA2,"")&
 IF(AD2=MIN(AB2,AD2,AF2,AH2,AJ2),AC2,"")&
 IF(AF2=MIN(AB2,AD2,AF2,AH2,AJ2),AE2,"")&
 IF(AH2=MIN(AB2,AD2,AF2,AH2,AJ2),AG2,"")&
 IF(AJ2=MIN(AB2,AD2,AF2,AH2,AJ2),AI2,"")
```

Or this Array Formula:

```
=INDEX(AA2:AI2,MATCH(1,(AB2:AJ2=MIN(AB2,AD2,AF2,AH2,AJ2))*(ISEVEN(COLUMN(AB2:AJ2))),0))
```

This will need to be array entered using Ctrl-Shift-Enter Instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Comment: i appreciate. is there is any better and clean way to do this? thanks in advance.

Comment: @FashionFiestas if I could have thought of one I would have included it.

Comment: @FashionFiestas see the edit I included a different version for older versions.

Answer (score 1):

`MIN` returns a value, not a cell reference, so you can't use it as input of `OFFSET`.

I'm not aware of any solution with built-in functions which would work on a not-contiguous range.

Comment: i appreciate. is there is any alternative formula? thanks

Answer (score 1):

For **pre-O365** versions of Excel, assuming the entries in the range `AB2,AD2,AF2,AH2,AJ2` are **non-negative**:

```
=OFFSET(
    INDEX(
        (AB2, AD2, AF2, AH2, AJ2),,,
        MATCH(1, FREQUENCY(0, (AB2, AD2, AF2, AH2, AJ2)), 0)
    ),,-1
)
```

Note the importance of the parentheses in the part:

`(AB2, AD2, AF2, AH2, AJ2)`